# Как связать две базы

Tags: php, mysql

Можно ли связать две базы, возможно при помощи оператора `where`?

Я хотел создать комментарии к самописным новостям, но когда я написал

```
 $resulc =mysql_query("select * from ` comment` where `new_id`   ='"$result['id']"' order by dask");
```

выводится только последняя новость, а комментариев вообще нет.
С помощью `echo $result;` пробовал, и выводил с помощью цикла `while fetch_array`.

Comment: почитайте про join. или дайте структуру таблиц

Answer (score 1):

Присоединяюсь к предыдущему коментатору, либо у вас просто ошибка в запросе вот тут:
`comment`
лишний пробел.